# What could be wrong when using Import for an XLSX?

Tags: import, excel

I am using MMA 11.2.0.0 on Win7X64.

```
Import["combined_analysis.xlsx", {"sheet1"}]
```

> Import::noelem: The Import element "sheet1" is not present when importing as XLSX.

In the xlsx file, I DID rename all sheets. But for testing purpose, I renamed the sheet that I want to import to various names. None worked.

What could be wrong?????

```
Import["combined_analysis.xlsx"]
```

Does work fine. Then I can select the data using

```
Import["combined_analysis.xlsx"][[4]]
```

for example. But what's wrong using the sheet name?

Comment: `Import["foo.xlsx", {"Sheets", "s1"}]` where "s1" is the sheet name, see the "Elements" section in reference page: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XLSX.html